# Made zoom on SVG file and mapping parts on Android

Tags: android, svg, mapping, zooming

As the title said, I have a SVG file on an android app. What I need to do is be able to make pinch zoom over the image and I need to mapping parts of the image.

Anybody knows if that is possible and have any idea about how to do it.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use that library => https://github.com/moagrius/TileView

Answer (score 0):

I hope this library might help you....
https://github.com/moagrius/TileView